# c# Regex - Check if condition in a number of a certain length is met

Tags: c#, regex

A friend of mine had this as a task for university.
He needed a **Regex** to check if a **9 digit long** number with leading `0+` has no more `0`s after another digit.

Examples:

```
000001111 - good
000000010 - bad
000000000 - good
001215341 - good
165160000 - bad
0165168546 - bad
```

After some time we both came up with `^\b([0]+[1-9]*)\b$`.
However this also allows the latest example/ **does not check for the correct length**. He ended up checking the length with an if-statement beforehand, but I just can't find my peace because of it.

Is there an more elegant way? One Regex to do the above, but also check the length?

Comment: More elegant, and regex? The if statement is far and away the better real solution IMO. Academically, it might not fit the requirements, but that would be a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead condition:

```
^(?=\d{9}$)0*[1-9]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X75KpU/1)

- `^`: Start
- `(?=\d{9}$)`: Lookahead condition to check for exact 9 digits
- `0*`: Match 0 or more `0`
- `[1-9]*`: Match 0 or more `[1-9]` digits
- `$`: End

Comment: Thank you. Also for the explanation, that helps a lot. I did not know about lookaheads. 0+ though for leading 0s :)